# jqgrid addXMLData() help?

Tags: xml, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

what is the xml format/structure that is required by addXMLData() function jqgrid?

Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of XML data for [addXMLData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods#grid_related_methods) method are defined by `xmlReader`. The most important restriction is that the data must be in the XML elements and not in the XML attributes. The exception is `id`. In the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#xml_data) you can find many examples. You can also parse the XML data yourself and use [data](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) parameter of jqGrid.